# Meaning of period symbol in this context?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

Can anyone tell me what does the period symbol represent in this context?

$5^5.2^2$

Comment: Doesn't look like standard notation, but I guess it indicates multiplication.  Where did you see this?

Comment: Multiplication.

Comment: I saw it on this site in the solution to the following problem https://brilliant.org/problems/6s-problem-6/#!/solution-comments/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dot is a multiplication symbol. It's relatively standard in some parts of the world (I've seen it used on Numberphile from time to time, for instance) to use a lower $.$ rather than a centered $\cdot$